# Trying to use GET on a weather api but python keeps adding a questionmark

Tags: python, api, request

So I wanted to try some things out with a weather api but I can't seem to get it working. When I run the code, the Python interpreter keeps adding a questionmark to my request so I just get a 404 response, not found.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json
url = "http://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se"

myResponse = requests.get(url,"api/category/pmp2g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16.158/lat/58.5812/data.json", verify=True)

if(myResponse.ok):
    jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)
    print("The response contains {0} properties".format(len(jData)))
    print("\n")
    for key in jData:
        print (key + " : " + jData[key])
else:
     myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

And this is my error message:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/?/category/pmp2g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16.158/lat/58.5812/data.json
```

As you can see it replaces the beginning of the request "api" with a questionmark. This is why it can't find the resource. Why does it do this?

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: Incorrect use of `Requests.Get`, see here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
myResponse = requests.get("{}/api/category/pmp2g/version/2/geotype/point/lon/16.158/lat/58.5812/data.json".format(url))
```

Currently you're passing the rest of URL as GET params.

From `requests` docs:

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

You can see that the URL has been correctly encoded by printing the URL:

```
>>> print(r.url)
http://httpbin.org/get?key2=value2&key1=value1
```